# How to move App Data from rooted Gingerbread to unrooted KitKat?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, 4.4-kitkat, app-data, device-migration

I want to move App Data of some apps from my rooted Galaxy S (Gingerbread 2.3.5) to unrooted Nexus 7 G1 (KitKat 4.4.2) & I don't want to root my Nexus 7. So, Titanium Backup restore on Nexus 7 isn't possible.

My Gingerbread device is already rooted to backup App Data & [App Data restore to unrooted KitKat device is also possible](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices). So, technically, the solution is feasible.

This is a headache for me because its a major version class shift (ICS+ versions are significantly different than prior versions). Please, help.

Comment: This might be a silly question: Can you backup your apps to your Google account? It should restore the apps and data for them without needing any 3rd party apps like Titanium or MyBackup. It's not ideal and Google state that it isn't a guarantee that your data will be backed up even using the Google Backup API. However, without root I can't see a way that you will be able to guarantee access to any /system or /data folders on the Nexus 7.

Comment: Sorry to double comment, from what people on XDA say, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=sv  Helium (previously Carbon) backup will restore your App AND your data without any root. The XDA users say they have tested on Nexus 7 with no root. I can't test it for you as all my devices are rooted!

Comment: @RossC 1. Google Backup isn't useful if app isn't designed for that. 2. Helium Backup isn't compatible with Gingerbread.

Comment: 1. It IS designed for that, it just isn't 100% reliable unfortunately. HOWEVER, that may just be a generic disclaimer saying they're not responsible for your data. It works fine for me most of the time. 2. Ah sorry I didn't see that in the description. I think your best bet is to backup to Google Play, and try to "Restore my Google Account" on the Nexus 7 after a clean factory reset. It's the best bet without rooting the device. Any of the apps that aren't Carbon require root for a backup of the data I'm afraid. Failing that I guess root > Titanium > unroot.

Comment: @RossC Oh, looks like you are talking about global Google backup, not API backup. If that's the case, factory reset just for app data of few apps is an overkill. Plus, it'd bring unwanted data too.

Comment: @RossC I am asking it because there can still be a way despite there's no root access. See: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices

Comment: I completely understand, and I won't drag this out any further. I'm still looking and I'll reply if I find anthing. The sticking point for me is Gingerbread. There are work arounds, the SDK, ADB etc but they all are 4.0+ for this (from what I can see thus far). I can't find a solution with the GB side of things on that device, but that isn't to say there's no way to do it. I'll keep looking, but why not TRY the Google Account route and see how you get on, if it doesn't work, you haven't lost anything at all! It woked for me on my S4 first time, perfectly. Google Account backup uses Google API!